# Angular Ag Grid - Has anyone figured out a way to wait for a cell node update to happen and THEN fire a function, like a callback?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am utilizing `cellChanged.node.setDataValue(fieldChanged, oldValue)` inside of the `(cellValueChanged)` event emitter, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to call a function once the `setDataValue` function has finished executing. I need to do this to do a check to see if a user has the permission to update a cell.

Here is the full code that checks:

```
if(this.showPaywallNotification) {

      // Okay, so the budget is above what we allow HOWEVER...
      if(budget > BUDGET_AMOUNT) {

      this.showPaywallNotification = false;
      cellChanged.node.setDataValue(fieldChanged, oldValue)

      // Note: This timeout is in place to prevent the infinite updating bug
      // This is problematic because if the user changes the cells fast enough, they can get around the paywall. If I change the timeout to be smaller, the resulting change triggers the update, which ends up creating an infinite loop of updates.
      setTimeout(() => {
           this.showPaywallNotification = true;
      }, 230)
  }
```

}

Is there a way I can replace my `setTimeout()` function with something better that can always ensure the user can't get around my paywall by just updating the cell faster than the timeout can execute?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve in your `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @Viqas I'm just creating a workaround to check against the paywall boolean. If I don't have the settimeout, it will constantly trigger a change to the cell edit since anytime the user goes over the budget, it reverts the cell to the previous value.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do polling. `setDataValue` is a not an async function.

Also, `onCellValueChanged` won't get called again if you call `node.setDataValue`.

Have a look at this plunk: [Cell Editing - Revert to old value](https://plnkr.co/edit/YpYwjuHYgUaFrEyH). Try updating any `Age` value to negative.

```
onCellValueChanged($event) {
  if ($event.colDef.field === 'age' && $event.newValue < 0) {
    // debugger
    $event.node.setDataValue('age', $event.oldValue);
    console.log('value reverted');
  }
}
```

Let me know if something is not clear, or this is not sufficient.